# Diferencia entre HTML object y JAVASCRIPT object y como acceder y dar atributos a javascript objects

Tags: javascript, html, object

```js
// //GLOBAL VARIABLES
var box = document.getElementById('game-board');
var cardElement;
var cardsInPlay= [];
var cardNodes = [];
var random;
var cards = [
  {
    rank: 'king',
    pic: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'king',
    pic: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'queen',
    pic: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'queen',
    pic: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png'
  }
];
var cardNodes = [];

//1. CREATE BOARD
function createBoard(){
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cardElement = document.createElement('img');
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
    box.appendChild(cardElement);
    cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCardAndRandomize);
    cardNodes.push(cardElement); // So now is a HTML node instead JS object (i can use setAttribute now)
  }
}
createBoard();

//2. FLIP CARDS RANDOMLY
function flipCardAndRandomize(){
  //Randomize the deck =>
  random = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
  this.setAttribute('src', cards[random].pic);
  cardsInPlay.push(cards[random].rank);
  console.log(this);
  match();
}

//3. CHECK IF MATCH
function match(){
  if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      console.log('MATCH');
    } else {
      console.log('TRY AGAIN');
      setTimeout(function(){
        // cardNodes[0].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png'); // Long way to do it
        // cardNodes[1].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        // cardNodes[2].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        // cardNodes[3].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        cardNodes.forEach(function(node){  // Short way to do it => Executes a function per each array element
          node.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        });
      },1000);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;

}

h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #0d2c40;
  font-size: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

p {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  font-family: raleway;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F15B31;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;

}

h2 {
  font-family: raleway;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0d2c40;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header {
  background-color: #F15B31;
  padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
}

main {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 35px auto
}

a {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

nav {
  background-color: #00A6B3;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

img {
  margin: 40px 8px 0 8px;
}

footer {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #0D2C40;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .08em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.copyright {
  float: left;
}

.message {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.name {
  color: #F15B31;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#game-board{
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

      <title>Memory card game</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1>Memory Game</h1>
      </header>
      <nav>
         <p><a href="#">INSTRUCTIONS</a><a href="#"> GAME</a></p>
      </nav>
      <main>
         <h2>INSTRUCTIONS</h2>
         <p>Concentration, also known as Match Match, Memory, Pelmanism, Shinkei-suijaku, Pexeso or simply Pairs, is a card game in which all of the cards are laid face down on a surface and two cards are flipped face up over each turn. The object of the game is to turn over pairs of matching cards.</p>
         <div id="game-board" class="board clearfix"></div>
      </main>
      <footer>
          <div class="clearfix">
          <p class="copyright">Copyright 2017</p>
          <p class="message">Created with &hearts; by <span class="name">GA</span></p>
              </div>
      </footer>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hoal buenas, 
Soy nuevo en **javascript**, y seguro es una pregunta tonta. 
Entiendo el DOM, poder acceder, con por ejemplo => `document.getElementById()` a un `HTML object` y darle `setAttribute` por ejemplo ya que YA ES UN `HTML OBJECT`.
Mi pregunta es: Si creo un `array`, es un `javascript object` no un `html object`, entonces me dice is not a `function...`
Como hago para poder darle atributos a un objeto creado en javsacript, que no este ya creado en el html. Debo => **document.createElement** en un loop por ejemplo y luego aplicar sobre ese elemento `setAttribute` siempre?
Un saludo

Comment: pon código sobre el que trabajas , para tener idea

Comment: Debes poner un ejemplo de codigo a lo que te refieres para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Era mas bien una pregunta generica, si tengo html ya puedo manipularlo, pero si creo un array como lo convierto en html object. En mi caso lo hice creando un loop y ahi creando elementos dinamicamente, al crearlos ya son html. y luego guarde en un nuevo array para darle setAttribute. Voy a subir un ejemplo de un juego de cartas. Gracias por tu ayuda Santiago.

Comment: Travv, pues functiona este juego, es muy simple, pero mi duda era esa, como dar setAttribute a arrays o objects creados. No sobre html elements

Comment: var a = 'fran';
  a.setAttribute('class', 'myClass'); // error: not a function
 
COMO PUEDO DARLE ATRIBUTO A 'fran' YA QUE NO ES UN HTML OBJECT??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Espera a que cargue el DOM dentro de un

```
setTimeout(function(){

///tus instrucciones de manipulación van aqui

})
```

Comment: Se que es super simple mi pregunta, pero me refiero a esto, quiero añadir clase a un elemento creado en javascript, no sobre uno que esta ya en html, como hago para poder dar setAttribute a 'fran' => 
```var a = 'fran';
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

setTimeout(function(){
  a.setAttribute('class', 'myClass'); // error: not a function
},1000);```

Answer (score 0):

Estas en lo correcto, para poder utilizar las funciones de javascript destinadas a cambiar propiedades de objetos HTML, debes tener un objeto del mismo tipo.
Eso lo consigues llamando como referencia a un objeto del DOM con un document.getElementById por ejemplo, o creando un objeto nuevo con el document.createElement();.

Lo que haces aqui esta correcto:

```
cardElement = document.createElement('img');
cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
box.appendChild(cardElement);
```

Para tu pregunta especifica que decía asi: "Mi pregunta es: Si creo un array, es un javascript object no un html object, entonces me dice is not a function..."
Puedes tener un Array (Javascript) que contenga objetos html, como lo haces aqui:

```
function createBoard(){
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {

    /**** IMPORTANTE REDECLARAR LA VARIABLE CON EL "VAR" YA QUE ESTAS DENTRO DE UN CICLO ***/
    var cardElement = document.createElement('img'); 

    /**** LUEGO DE CREAR TU OBJETO, PUEDES AGREGAR LOS EVENTOS Y ATRIBUTOS ****/
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
    cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCardAndRandomize);

    /*** APENDIZAS AL DOM O A OTRO OBJETO HTML****/
    box.appendChild(cardElement); //AQUI APENDIZAS AL DOM O A OTRO OBJETO HTML

    /*** CUANDO LO GUARDAS EN EL ARRAY DE JAVASCRIPT, TU OBJETO SIGUE ESTANDO COMO REFERENCIA, Y PUEDES CAMBIAR SUS ATRIBUTOS LLAMANDO AL ARRAY Y SU POSICIÓN***/
    cardNodes.push(cardElement);

    /*** CREO QUE AQUÍ ESTA EL PROBLEMA, YA QUE PARA APUNTAR A TU OBJETO DENTRO DEL ARRAY, DEBES UTILIZAR LA POSICION DE TU OBJETO EN EL ARRAY ***/
    cardElement[0].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, eso ultimo de cardElement[0].setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png'); no va a funcionar ya que mi array es cards[ ] cardElement son las 4 imagenes creadas dinamicamente, y a todas ellas les doy back.png.
Igualmente mi duda era que me dara que no es una funcion, como le doy clase a 'fran' en este caso para luego en css poder cambiarlo de color por ejemplo ? Ya que no es un string que este en html sino una en javascript =>

**var a = 'fran';                                                      
  a.setAttribute('class', 'miClase'); // error: not a function**